# Disable iframe injection in cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe, single-page-application

How to `disable iframe injection` in `cordova apps` using *global configuration?*

Below is the respective screen,

[image: Iframe injected imae]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can achieve it restricting the whitelist in your application, with this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist (included in the lasts versions of cordova), only allow the URLs of your app, so all the rest of URLs should be blocked

This is only the theory, so please, share your results :)

Comment: had to put check on submit level